# Python 2.7 - can't add ctypes due to; error: package directory 'ctypes' does not exist

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, ctypes, setup.py

I'd like to develop in Python 2.7 on Windows RT.

However, I can not get the ctypes package added:

```
C:\windows\system32>"c:\program files (rtds)\python_2.7\python.exe" "C:\Users\Hazel\Downloads\ctypes-1.0.2\setup.py" install
running install
running build
running build_py
error: package directory 'ctypes' does not exist

C:\windows\system32>
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: ctypes is an optional component of the Python standard library that depends on an existing port of [libffi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libffi). I don't know what, if anything, needs to be done to port libffi to WinRT / ARM.

Comment: I have libffi added but I don't know if it is working

Comment: Dead project...